# Static Factory Methods getType & newType examples

Tags: java, static-methods, effective-java

In Effective Java , Item 1, towards the end of the this section on Static Factory methods, Joshua Bloch describes common names for static factory methods.  Two of these names, get*Type* and new*Type*, are a little confusing for me.

**Quote [Bloch, p. 10]**

> getType - Like getInstance, but used when the factory method is in a different class.  *Type* indicates the type of object returned by the factory method.
>
> newType - Like newInstance, but used when the factory method is in a different class.  *Type* indicates the type of object returned by the factory method.

What would be the use case for having static factory methods in a different class?  Is there an example of this pattern in use within the Java API?

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the use case for having static factory methods in a different class?

The use case is simply, well... when you've got static factory methods in a different class. Your code could conceivably be organized in such a way that this works out to be more appropriate. There isn't really "the" use case, it very much depends on your situation, requirements, and style.

The `getType()` and `newType()` are not meant to be taken literally; they are meant to indicate a naming convention as in `Something.newWidget()` or whatever.

An example of this in the Java API is e.g. [`Channels`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Channels.html), where it makes sense to organize multiple related factory methods in the same class. Semantically, a method named `Channels.newInstance()` wouldn't really make a lot of sense, since it doesn't instantiate a new `Channels`.

Another example is the commonly used [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

A lot more examples in the API can be found by browsing [the 'n' section of the documentation index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index-files/index-14.html) (look for "new*").

None of this stuff is really hard and fast concrete rules, just general guidelines and options. What *you* need to do is whatever you need to do make sure your code is clear, concise, maintainable, and flexible. So you make the call when designing and writing your software.